# jQuery Autocomplete doesn't work in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-autocomplete, turbolinks

I'm trying to integrate jQuery UI Autocomplete in my Rails 4.0 application like described in this Railscast: [102-AutoCompleteAssociationRevised](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised).

Unfortunately, the autocompletion doesn't work. I don't get any suggestions although the rendered HTML looks fine:

```
<input id="plan_part_name" type="text" name="plan[part_name]" data-autocomplete-source="["foo","food","foobar"]"></input>
```

I also deactivated Turbolinks, but nothing changed...

In my Gemfile I included `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'` and my **application.js** looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl
//= require_tree .
```

This is the form, that I'm using, **edit.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_for [@project, @plan], remote: true, html: { id: "edit-form-#{@plan.id}" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.text_field :part_name, data: {autocomplete_source: %w[ foo food foobar ]}  %>

  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

**autocomplete.js.coffee:**

```
autocomplete = ->
  $('#plan_part_name').autocomplete
    source: $('#plan_part_name').data('autocomplete-source')

$(document).ready(autocomplete)
$(document).on('page:load', autocomplete)
```

Comment: Isn't your HTML markup broken (double quotes within double quotes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

My edit form got rendered by Ajax request so I had to change the Javascript file (autocomplete.js.coffee) from:

```
$(document).on('page:load', autocomplete)
```

to:

```
$(document).on('page:update', autocomplete)
```

to work work properly with Turbolinks. You'll find more information in the [Turbolinks Readme](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/blob/master/README.md#events).